# How to use "rule-name-agenda-filter" requesting Kie-Server using Http Json (rest api)

Tags: drools

I deploy a project with some rules using workbench(7.17.0), and then request kie-server like this:

url: `http://*.*.*.*:*/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/instances/LtangsTestProject`

body:

```
{
  "commands": [
    {
      "insert": {
        "out-identifier": "person",
        "object": {
          "com.riskspace.ltangstestproject.Person": {
            "name": "linweijiang",
            "age": 27,
            "balance": 120000.00
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "fire-all-rules": {
        "out-identifier": "firedActivations",
        "rule-name-equals-agenda-filter": "TreeTest_0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I was expecting the request to fire only one rule called `TreeTest_0`, turns out that it still fired all rules.

I checked the drools project(7.42.0-SNAPSHOT), find codes bellow:

```
        public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader,
                                UnmarshallingContext context) {
            String max = null;
            String outIdentifier = null;
            while ( reader.hasMoreChildren() ) {
                reader.moveDown();
                if ( "max".equals( reader.getNodeName() ) ) {
                    max = reader.getValue();
                } else if ( "out-identifier".equals( reader.getNodeName() ) ) {
                    outIdentifier = reader.getValue();
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException( "fire-all-rules does not support the child element name=''" + reader.getNodeName() + "' value=" + reader.getValue() + "'" );
                }
                reader.moveUp();
            }

            FireAllRulesCommand cmd;

            if ( max != null ) {
                cmd = new FireAllRulesCommand( Integer.parseInt( max ) );
            } else {
                cmd = new FireAllRulesCommand();
            }
            if ( outIdentifier != null ) {
                cmd.setOutIdentifier(outIdentifier);
            }
            return cmd;
        }
```

I am wondering why kie-server rest api do not support rule name filter.

Please help, how can I make it, fire only rules I need, instead of firing all.

Thanks man.

Comment: Your first question (`I am wondering why kie-server rest api do not support rule name filter`) is off topic -- that's something only the designers of the application can answer. However the second question (how to only fire certain rules) is on topic.

Comment: The property is explicitly `"agenda-filter"` on fire-all-rules (not rule-name-equals-agenda-filter). But I can't find any examples of what the syntax is supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks man. I trid "agenda-filter", still didn't work.